# Convert bulleted list HTML code to Markdown in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, text, html, markdown, command-line

I have this text to manipulate in AppleScript (e.g. the text of a variable):

```
Example note exported from Apple.

<ul>
  <li>Indent</li>
  <ul>
    <li>*Further* indent</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Even **further **indent. With a [link](https://duck.com).</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>

End note.
```

I'm converting it all to Markdown from HTML. I need to clean up this remaining bit of HTML which is the bullet list, so that the result is (with real tabs as indent space):

```
Example note exported from Apple.

- Indent
    - *Further* indent
        - Even **further **indent. With a [link](https://duck.com).

End note.
```

It has to be able to cater to nested indenting to any 'n' number of levels, and with possibly some rich text inside the items such as this example. I prefer Markdown output to use hyphens and a tab for the indenting.

It also has to be containable inside the applescript - no external `.py` files etc, and to not require `homebrew` or a third party tool to be installed.

Comment: I broke this out into two with a sister question for `<ol>` lists to markdown here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/404949/163629

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, as coded, is intended to work with *bulleted list* **HTML** *code* as shown in the **OP**, meaning that what is passed in the *variable* is just the relevant *code* to define the *bulleted list* and not other arbitrary **HTML** *code*.

As coded, it will produce the appropriate output for variations of *bulleted list* **HTML** *code* as well, not just the specific *example* shown herein. This has been tested on a variety of other samples containing just *bulleted list* **HTML** *code* and produces the relevant output for it as does the *example* herein.

```
--  # Define exportedNote variable containing the bulleted list HTML code.

set exportedNote to "<ul>
  <li>Indent</li>
  <ul>
    <li>*Further* indent</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Even **further** indent. With a [link](https://duck.com).</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>"

--  # Create an AppleScript list from the lines of bulleted list HTML code.

set exportedNoteList to paragraphs of exportedNote

--  # Process the list, acting only on items that contain "</li>" 
--  # as they are the only ones relevant to converting the 
--  # bulleted list HTML code to Markdown.

set tempList to {}
repeat with i from 1 to the number of items in exportedNoteList
    if item i of exportedNoteList contains "<li>" then
        set thisItem to item i of exportedNoteList
        set thisItem to findAndReplaceInText(thisItem, "</li>", "")
        set numberOfLeadingSpaces to ((offset of "<" in thisItem) - 1)
        if numberOfLeadingSpaces is less than 4 then
            set searchString to characters 1 thru numberOfLeadingSpaces of thisItem & "<li>" as text
            set thisItem to findAndReplaceInText(thisItem, searchString, "- ")
            set end of tempList to thisItem
        end if
        if numberOfLeadingSpaces is greater than 3 then
            set searchString to characters 1 thru numberOfLeadingSpaces of thisItem & "<li>" as text
            set thisItem to findAndReplaceInText(thisItem, searchString, "- ")
            set numberOfLeadingTabs to (numberOfLeadingSpaces / 2) as integer
            repeat with i from 1 to (numberOfLeadingTabs - 1)
                set thisItem to tab & thisItem
            end repeat
            set end of tempList to thisItem
        end if
    end if
end repeat

--  # Update the contents of the exportedNoteList
--  # list to contain only the relevant list items.

set exportedNoteList to tempList

--  # Convert the exportedNoteList list to text.

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set convertedNote to text items of exportedNoteList
set convertedNote to convertedNote as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {}

--  # 'return' is only used to show its value in Script Editor. Use
--  # the convertedNote variable as needed in the working code.

return convertedNote


--  # Handler(s)

--  # Note: Handlers may be placed as one chooses as appropriate.
--  # My preference is at the bottom of the rest of the code.

on findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end findAndReplaceInText
```

**Result:**

```
"- Indent
    - *Further* indent
        - Even **further** indent. With a [link](https://duck.com)."
```

Which displays as the following in a browser on this web site:

- Indent

  - *Further* indent

    - Even **further** indent. With a [link](https://duck.com).

Comment: @ἐλευθερία, I have update my answer to include only **AppleScript** _code_ other then it's `do shell script` _command_ and will handle other examples of _bulleted list_ **HTML** _code_ as stated within the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However the example in the question did show that the result should include all lines from source, not just the bullet lines. (I've now updated Q to reflect answer update to clarify processing any n number of bullet indent levels, thanks.) In the meantime I'll hack around with this updated answer to see if I can get it to spit out other non-bullet list lines.

Answer (score 0):

I will also answer this question with an alternative method I worked out:

```
set exportedNote to "Example note exported from Apple.

<ul>
  <li>Indent</li>
  <ul>
    <li>*Further* indent</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Even **further **indent. With a [link](https://duck.com).</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>

End note."

set deleteHTMLline to {"<ul>"}
set exportedNote to deleteLinesFromText(exportedNote, deleteHTMLline) of me as text
set deleteHTMLline to {"</ul>"}
set exportedNote to deleteLinesFromText(exportedNote, deleteHTMLline) of me as text

set exportedNote to replace_chars(exportedNote, "      <li>", tab & tab & "- ") of me as text
set exportedNote to replace_chars(exportedNote, "    <li>", tab & "- ") of me as text
set exportedNote to replace_chars(exportedNote, "  <li>", "- ") of me as text
set exportedNote to replace_chars(exportedNote, "</li>", "") of me as text

return exportedNote

on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    return this_text
end replace_chars

on deleteLinesFromText(theText, deletePhrase)
    set newText to ""
    try
        set textList to paragraphs of theText
        repeat with i from 1 to count of textList
            set thisLine to item i of textList
            if thisLine does not contain deletePhrase then
                set newText to newText & thisLine & return
            end if
        end repeat
        if newText is not "" then set newText to text 1 thru -2 of newText
    on error
        set newText to theText
    end try
    return newText
end deleteLinesFromText
```

**Result:**

```
Example note exported from Apple.

- Indent
    - *Further* indent
        - Even **further **indent. With a [link](https://duck.com).

End note.
```

---

**Notes:**

Similarly to the main answer, if you want to convert further levels of indentation you'll need to add extra lines for it.

This sample code only converts three levels. To add a fourth, you can add at the top of the `set exportedNote to replace_chars` section:

```
set exportedNote to replace_chars(exportedNote, "        <li>", tab & tab & tab & "- ") of me as text
```

Add deeper levels on the top going down in chronological order with two more spaces before each `<li>` and one more `tab &`.

If anyone has code to be able to convert any `n` number of indentation levels, please chime in or submit edits.